# Are weak set values change its indexes in every reload (Javascript)?

Tags: javascript, html, constructor, javascript-objects, prototypejs

I've created a weak set in js program and pass an object to its **constructor** then I used **.add** method to add other objects and then I've console set to result but I've noticed after reloading my page arrangement of these objects in the weak set is changed why?

and I want to know if **add** method works like **unshift** or **push** in array? thanks.

```
let newWeakSet = new WeakSet([{A: 1}]);//constructor and add function accepts only one object to add to set.


let obj_2 = {B:2};
let obj_4 = {D:4};

newWeakSet.add(obj_2)
newWeakSet.add({C:3})
newWeakSet.add(obj_4);

console.log(newWeakSet);
```

[image: this is first console for the above code]

[image: and this is the second console for the same code]

[image: third console]

Comment: Well, `WeakSet`s are not ordered - they're not even iterable! - so I don't see a reason why it should be the same every time. Notice that these are not "indices", that's just your devtool's way of displaying internal values.